# How do I use Page Break in Dompdf laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-5.5, dompdf

I'm having trouble designing the pdf of my system. here's a pic of my pdf:

[image: PDF FILE]

What I want to do is to limit the number of items in the table by 10 items after that the rest goes to the next page with the same header and footer which is fixed already. just like this:
[Purchase Request PDF](https://www.scribd.com/document/392474293/Purchase-Request)

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>PDF</title>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        #items tr{border:1px solid #000000;}
        #items tbody tr td{border:1px solid #000000;}
        #items thead td{background-color:#231F20;color:#FFFFFF;}

        .header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top: -40px; right: 0px;}
        .footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom: 200px; right: 0px;}
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/lato.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Libre+Barcode+128" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="header">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-3" style="font-family: 'Libre Barcode 128', cursive; font-size: 35px;padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;">{{$pr->pr_form_no}}</div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
        <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' style="border-width: 0 !important;padding:0px 0px 0px 60px;">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px;"><img src="{{asset('images/sfclogo.png')}}" width="50px" height="50px"></td>
                <td>
                    <table style="text-align: center;style='width:45%'">
                        <tr><td>REPUBLIC OF THE PHILIPPINES</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>PROVINCE OF LA UNION</td></tr>
                        <tr><td>CITY OF SAN FERNANDO</td></tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <th style="padding-top: 10px;padding-left: 10px"><p style="background-color: #000;color: #FFF; text-align: center;padding: 10px;">PR</p></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;color: white;background-color: black; font-size: 18px">
            PURCHASE REQUEST
        </div><br>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
                <table style='width:100%;border:1px solid #000000;font-size:11pt;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5' class='font1'>
                <tr>
                    <td style='width:40%'>
                        <table style='width:90%;padding-right: 0px;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:100%;padding:1px;padding-left:10px;' colspan='2'>DEPARTMENT:</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:100%;padding:0px;padding-left:10px;' colspan='2'>{{$dept->office_name}}<hr style='color:#000000;height:1px;margin-bottom:3px;margin-top:0px;padding-left:10px;' /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:15%;padding:1px;padding-left:10px;'>SECTION:</td>
                                <td style='width:75%;padding:0px;padding-left:0px;'>{{$section->office_name}}<hr style='color:#000000;height:1px;margin-bottom:3px;margin-top:0px;' /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style='width:30%;'>
                        <table style='width:90%;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:20%;padding:1px;'>PR No.</td>
                                <td style='width:70%;padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>{{$pr->pr_form_no}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:20%;padding:1px;'>SAI No.</td>
                                <td style='width:70%;padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:20%;padding:1px;'>ObR No.</td>
                                <td style='width:70%;padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style='width:30%'>
                        <table style='width:95%;' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:15%;padding:1px;'>Date</td>
                                <td style='width:70%;padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'>&nbsp;{{$dt->toFormattedDateString()}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:15%;padding:1px;'>Budget</td>
                                <td style='width:70%;padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000000;'><strong>&nbsp;PHP {{number_format($pr->budget_alloc,2)}}</strong></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style='width:15%;padding:1px;'>Supplier</td>
                                <td style='width:70%;padding:0px;border-bottom:1px solid #000;'>&nbsp;{{$pr->supplier_type}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
      </div>
  </div>

 <div class="footer">
    <div class="row">
        <table style='width:100%;border:1px solid #000000;font-size:12px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:40px;' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3' class='font1'>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:39%; font-weight:bold;text-align:left;border:1px solid #000000;'>
                REQUESTING OFFICE<br/><br/><br/><br/>
                </td>
                <td style='width:60%;border:1px solid #000000;vertical-align:top;font-weight:bold;' colspan='2' rowspan='3'>
                PURPOSE<br/>
                <div style='width:100%;text-align:center;font-weight:normal;font-size:11pt;' class='font1'>
                    {{$pr->purpose}}
                </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='border:1px solid #000000;height:19px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;'>
                {{$pr->requestor_name}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000;text-transform:uppercase;height:19px;font-weight:bold'>
                {{$pr->requestor_position}}
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan='3' style='background-color:#000000;height:20px;'>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:33%; font-weight:bold;text-align:left;border:1px solid #000000;'>
                APPROPRIATION AVAILABLE
                </td>
                <td style='width:33%; font-weight:bold;text-align:left;border:1px solid #000000;'>
                FUNDS AVAILABLE
                </td>
                <td style='width:33%; font-weight:bold;text-align:left;border:1px solid #000000;'>
                APPROVED
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='border:1px solid #000000;height:25px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;'>

                </td>
                <td style='border:1px solid #000000;height:25px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;'>

                </td>
                <td style='border:1px solid #000000;height:25px;text-align:center;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:bold;'>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style='width:33%; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000;text-transform:uppercase;'>
                {{$aa->name}}<br/>
                {{$aa->position}}
                </td>
                <td style='width:33%; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000;text-transform:uppercase;'>
                {{$c->name}}<br/>
                {{$c->position}}
                </td>
                <td style='width:33%; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000;text-transform:uppercase;'>
                {{$approval->name}}<br/>
                {{$approval->position}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div style='float:left;font-weight:normal;font-style:italic;font-size:7pt;width:40%;text-align:left;'>{{$created_code}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content" >
      <div class="row">
        <table style='width:100%;font-size:14px;text-align:center;border:1px solid #000000;' id='items'  cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td style='width:7%;font-weight:bold;'>ITEM NO.</td>
                    <td style='width:7%;font-weight:bold;'>QTY</td>
                    <td style='width:7%;font-weight:bold;'>UNIT</td>
                    <td style='width:49%;font-weight:bold;'>DESCRIPTION</td>
                    <td style='width:15%;font-weight:bold;'>ESTIMATED UNIT OF</td>
                    <td style='width:15%;font-weight:bold;'>ESTIMATED COST</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>    

            <tbody >
                @foreach($list as $indexKey => $list)

                <tr>
                  <td>{{$indexKey}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->pr_qty}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->pr_unit}}</td>
                  <td>{{$list->pr_description}}</td>
                  <td  style='text-align: right;'>{{$list->pr_cost_per_unit}}</td>
                  <td style='text-align: right;'>{{$list->pr_estimated_cost}}</td>
                </tr>

                @if($indexKey >= 9)
                        @break
                @endif

                @endforeach

                @for($i = $count; $i < 10; $i++)
                    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td>&nbsp;<td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
                @endfor

            </tbody>

            <tfoot>
                <tr style="background-color: #b0b1b2;">
                  <td colspan="5" style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">GRAND TOTAL</td>
                  <td style="text-align: right; font-weight: bold;">
                    {{number_format($grand_total,2)}}
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
      </div>
  </div>



</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I already attempted to use the break function of the blade to stop the loop when the items shown is already 10.

*Also sorry if the code looks like hell.

Answer (score 6):

you can use some css styling for it just like below:

```
<style>
.page-break {
 page-break-after: always;
}
</style>
  <h1>page</h1>
   <div class="page-break"></div>
  <h1>Someother Page</h1>
```

if you want to make a page break after for example 5 divs then you can do something like this:

```
@php $check=0 @endphp
@foreach($array as $item)
@php $check++ @endphp
  <!-- your code or something like divs -->
@if( $check % 5 == 0 ) 
     @php echo '<div class="page-break"></div>'; @endphp .... 
 @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope you will get the idea from it.

Comment: what if it's a table?

Comment: you can do it for tables too just like the same. only the $check variable would do the trick.

Comment: just grab this `div` in `<tr><td>div here</td></tr>`

Comment: thank you. Well it did break but why did my header and footer not replicate?

Comment: just include it again in the if condition after page break, maybe it will work than.

Comment: like this? `   @if( $check % 12 == 0 )
        <tr><td colspan="6"><div class="page-break"></div></td></tr>
        @include('pr.pr-print-header')
   @include('pr.pr-print-footer')
    @endif`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183171/discussion-between-naveed-ali-and-reinhard-lohengramm).